# Does null set a default argument in a bound function, with JS bind?

Tags: javascript, function, functional-programming, bind

Observe this code:

```js
function adder(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
const adderFive = adder.bind(null, 5);
let pauloAgeInFuture = adderFive(41, 1) // 

console.log(pauloAgeInFuture); //->46
console.log(adderFive(5, 10)); //->10
```

Is the 2nd argument ignored because 1) since using null I'm saying that the bound value (5) is the default b arg, OR 2) since passing 5 as argument I'm saying that the function is waiting just up to one more argument (the first to be passed)?

Comment: The first argument to `bind()` is the `this` context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument to `bind()` is the `this` context that will be provided when calling the function. Since your function doesn't use `this`, this argument is simply ignored in your example.

The remaining arguments get inserted at the front of the argument list, followed by any arguments that are passed to the bound function. So when you call

```
adderFive(41, 1)
```

it's equivalent to calling

```
adder(5, 41, 1)
```

`adder` only uses the first two arguments, so this returns `5 + 41`.